# MacOSX python error on import

Tags: import, pygame, simplecv

Ive recently installed SimpleCV using the osX-Lion setup instructions in page https://github.com/ingenuitas/simplecv

Then I type python in Terminal and when I try the following I get an error.

```
import SimpleCV
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Abort trap: 6
```

However I get no errors when i try to import pygame myself. Any fix for this?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. Maybe you want to install [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and run your [python scripts](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) under the debugger. I once had a mysterious pygame crash and was able to find the root cause this way (pygame crashed when trying to render a text from an empty string, but this bug is already fixed).

Comment: what version of pygame are you using?

Comment: Its passed far away now:D Ive installed the superpack on windows coz it was quite in a rush coding quest:)

Comment: Same problem on ML. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use and follow this instructions of the [new](https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv) repository, the you are [using](https://github.com/ingenuitas/simplecv) have this Alert messages.

> THE SIMPLECV REPO HAS MOVED (As of 4/17/13)

Says the repository title.

> WARNING: The REPO here is for legacy purposes only